# How to protect files in a LAMP server?

Tags: php, html, web, server

I made a contact form in PhP that send the users email to a "email.txt"-document. The only problem is that anybody can see the document in the URL "example.com/email.txt".

My PHP code look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <?PHP
        $email = $_POST["emailaddress"];

        $to = "email@example.com";
        $subject = "New Email Address for Mailing List";
        $headers = "From: $email\n";

        $message = "A visitor to your site has sent the following email address to be added to your mailing list.\n

        Email Address: $email";

        $user = "$email";
        $usersubject = "Thank You";
        $userheaders = "From: email@example.com\n";

        $usermessage = "Thank you for subscribing to our mailing list.";

        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

        mail($user,$usersubject,$usermessage,$userheaders);

        $fh = fopen("email.txt", "a");
        fwrite($fh, $email);
        fclose($fh);

        ?>

        <html>
            <body>
                <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div align="center">Thank You, Your Information Has Been Submitted</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </body>
</html>
```

Anyone now how I can protect the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the file so it exists in a directory **outside** the HTTP server's root directory.

e.g. The directory structure of my server looks something like:

```
/hosts/example.com/apache  # For server configuration files
/hosts/example.com/pages   # For normal files to be served
/hosts/example.com/data    # For data files (like the one you are talking about)
/hosts/example.com/logs    # For log files
/hosts/example.com/stats   # For reports generated from log files
```

---

Alternatively (but with added complexity), use a RDBMS instead.

---

Alternatively (but with more risk of a security problem if the configuration broke), configure the server to deny access to that file specifically. e.g. With a `<Files>` block and [Allow/Deny](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) directives in Apache.